# Function signature-like expressions as C++ template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I was looking at Don Clugston's [FastDelegate](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx) mini-library and noticed a weird syntactical trick with the following structure:

```
TemplateClass< void( int, int ) > Object;
```

It almost appears as if a function signature is being used as an argument to a template instance declaration.

This technique (whose presence in FastDelegate is apparently due to one Jody Hagins) was used to simplify the declaration of template instances with a semi-arbitrary number of template parameters.

To wit, it allowed this something like the following:

```
// A template with one parameter
template<typename _T1>
struct Object1
{
    _T1 m_member1;
};

// A template with two parameters
template<typename _T1, typename _T2>
struct Object2
{
    _T1 m_member1;
    _T2 m_member2;
};

// A forward declaration
template<typename _Signature>
struct Object;

// Some derived types using "function signature"-style template parameters
template<typename _Dummy, typename _T1>
struct Object<_Dummy(_T1)> : public Object1<_T1> {};

template<typename _Dummy, typename _T1, typename _T2>
struct Object<_Dummy(_T1, _T2)> : public Object2<_T1, _T2> {};

// A. "Vanilla" object declarations
Object1<int> IntObjectA;
Object2<int, char> IntCharObjectA;

// B. Nifty, but equivalent, object declarations
typedef void UnusedType;
Object< UnusedType(int) > IntObjectB;
Object< UnusedType(int, char) > IntCharObjectB;

// C. Even niftier, and still equivalent, object declarations
#define DeclareObject( ... ) Object< UnusedType( __VA_ARGS__ ) >
DeclareObject( int ) IntObjectC;
DeclareObject( int, char ) IntCharObjectC;
```

Despite the real whiff of hackiness, I find this kind of spoofy emulation of variadic template arguments to be pretty mind-blowing.

The real meat of this trick seems to be the fact that I can pass textual constructs like "Type1(Type2, Type3)" as arguments to templates. So here are my questions: How exactly does the compiler interpret this construct? Is it a function signature? Or, is it just a text pattern with parentheses in it? If the former, then does this imply that any arbitrary function signature is a valid type as far as the template processor is concerned?

A follow-up question would be that since the above code sample is valid code, why doesn't the C++ standard just allow you to do something like the following, which does not compile?

```
template<typename _T1>
struct Object
{
    _T1 m_member1;
};

// Note the class identifier is also "Object"
template<typename _T1, typename _T2>
struct Object
{
    _T1 m_member1;
    _T2 m_member2;
};

Object<int> IntObject;
Object<int, char> IntCharObject;
```

Comment: +1, great question and I'm a big fan of the library in question.

Comment: See paragraph "C++ Function Types As A DSL" from [this article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/11/expressive-c-fun-with-function-composition/)

Comment: For another way to emulate variadic template arguments see http://templog.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/templog/code/trunk/tuples.h?revision=47&view=markup

Answer (score 48, accepted):

With regards to your first question - about the type `int(char, float)` - this is a valid C++ type and is the type of a function that takes in a `char` and a `float` and returns an `int`.  Note that this is the type of the actual function, not a function pointer, which would be an `int (*) (char, float)`.  The actual type of any function is this unusual type.  For example, the type of

```
void DoSomething() {
    /* ... */
}
```

is `void ()`.

The reason that this doesn't come up much during routine programming is that in most circumstances you can't declare variables of this type.  For example, this code is illegal:

```
void MyFunction() { 
    void function() = DoSomething; // Error!
}
```

However, one case where you do actually see function types used is for passing function pointers around:

```
void MyFunction(void FunctionArgument()) {
     /* ... */
}
```

It's more common to see this sort of function written to take in a function pointer, but it's perfectly fine to take in the function itself.  It gets casted behind-the-scenes.

As for your second question, why it's illegal to have the same template written with different numbers of arguments, I don't know the exactly wording in the spec that prohibits it, but it has something to do with the fact that once you've declared a class template, you can't change the number of arguments to it.  However, you can provide a partial specialization over that template that has a different number of arguments, provided of course that the partial specialization only specializes over the original number of arguments.  For example:

```
template <typename T> class Function;
template <typename Arg, typename Ret> class Function<Ret (Arg)> { 
    /* ... */
};
```

Here, `Function` always takes one parameter.  The template specialization takes in two arguments, but the specialization is still only over one type (specifically, `Ret (Arg)`).

Comment: Very nifty. The idea of a "type" of a function is pretty much outside of day-to-day C++ concept space, which is why this trick seemed so weird to me at first. But so if "void( int )" is a type, can one have, for example, a type which is a pointer to "void( int )"? Would that be the same thing as a function pointer?

Comment: Aha, hence the "correct" function pointer syntax, e.g. "void (*fp)() = & SomeFunction;". And also the dereferenced function call "(*fp)();" It seems kinda crappy to me that there are compilers that allow you to forgo the address-of and dereference operators...it makes the function type and function pointer type seem like the same thing, when they apparently are not.

Comment: @Jeff Lee- The compilers actually have to let you get away with this.  The C++ ISO spec (section 4.3.1) mentions that any function can implicitly be converted into a pointer to that function.  I think it's for C compatibility.

Comment: @templatetypedef - Does that contradict Clugston's claim in the linked article, or is he talking about something else: "Some compilers (most notably MSVC 6 and 7) will let you omit the &, even though it is non-standard and confusing. More standard-compliant compilers (e.g., GNU G++ and MSVC 8 (a.k.a. VS 2005)) require it, so you should definitely put it in."

Comment: In the context of raw functions you don't need the &, but for pointers-to-member-function the & is necessary.  I'm not sure what Clugston meant in that article, but it seems like he was slightly mistaken.  Just a guess.

Comment: Yeah, the context was instance method pointers, so it seems he actually agrees with you.

Comment: Although I agree you shouldn't use macros varargs, but why isn't __VA_ARGS__ a part of C++? It was added in C++11

Comment: @sasha.sochka- At the time I wrote this, I didn't know that C++11 had added `__VA_ARGS__`; it wasn't supported in C++03.  Thanks for letting me know about that... I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

```
int* int_pointer;    // int_pointer   has type "int*"
int& int_reference;  // int_reference has type "int&"
int  int_value;      // int_value     has type "int"

void (*function_pointer)(int, int);    // function_pointer has type
                                       // "void (*)(int, int)"
void (&function_reference)(int, int);  // function_reference has type
                                       // "void (&)(int ,int)"
void function(int, int);               // function has type
                                       // "void(int, int)"

template<>
struct Object1<void(int, int)>
{
    void m_member1(int, int);  // wait, what?? not a value you can initialize.
};
```

Comment: Right, that's definitely correct. Although in my example, the declaration that takes a function signature as a template parameter is not Object1. Rather, the declaration is being filtered through a derived class called "Object", which extracts individual types out of the signature.