# What <void(void)> means in template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I've found this code in the project I'm working:

```
template<typename T>
class SomeClass
{
};
typedef SomeClass<void(void)> SomeType;
```

What means `<void(void)>` construction? Can you please explain in a simple sample how a construction like this one may be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the type parameter is a function type (note, not a function pointer, but a function type) that takes no parameters, and returns no value.

You can even define function parameters in such a way:

```
void f (void(void));
```

That will decay to a function pointer when passed (just like an array parameter decays to a pointer).

Comment: Do you know some articles about this feature? I can't find any good references for it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, there is a very good question and answer about it here on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642079/function-signature-like-expressions-as-c-template-arguments).
I couldn't find anything else though, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I've found <functional> header and trying this in code as a very nice reference:) I'm starting to understand the concept.

Answer (score 1):

`T` here is a type of function that returns nothing and takes no arguments.