# Difference between a function pointer as template argument and a function signature as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, function-signature

What is the difference between below syntax:

```
template<typename T>
struct A { ... };

A<void (*)()> o1; // <--- ok
A<void()> o2;  // <----- ??
```

I want to know the practical use of the 2nd syntax apart from libraries (I checked that we cannot declare object of `void()` inside `A`). I have referred this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642079/function-signature-like-expressions-as-c-template-arguments), but that din't help.

Answer (score 1):

`void()` is the type of a function taking no arguments, and returning nothing.

`void(*)()` is the type of a pointer to a function taking no arguments, and returning nothing.

As an example of where `void()` is used and is useful, look at `std::function` -- the syntax it uses is much nicer than if you had to pass in a function pointer signature.  You can use the exact same syntax when you mean "I want to tell this template class the signature of a call".

Mainly, this is just syntactic sugar.  But sugar is the spice of life.