# C++11 What does this line of code do?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was browsing through [Nano-signal-slot](http://code.google.com/p/nano-signal-slot/) source code and hoping it could help me implement signals and slots functionality into my application using C++11 and I came across a portion of code that I haven't seen before.

Portion of code:

```
/* ... */

template <typename Re_t> class function;
template <typename Re_t, typename... Args>
class function<Re_t(Args...)>
{
    void *m_this_ptr;
    Re_t(*m_stub_ptr)(void*, Args...);

/* ... */
```

More specifically:

```
class function<Re_t(Args...)>
```

What does  do after the class name?

Comment: It's a variadic template, note the ... operator (multiple template arguments)

Comment: It allows you to specify the argument types of the function type (I'm presuming you're referring to the `(Args...)` portion). BTW, off-topic, why don't you have a look at [Qt](http://qt-project.org/), it has a straightforward and extensive (and thread-safe) signal/slot mechanism built in.

Comment: Is it right to call it a variadic template? I'd say it's a variadic template specialisation of a non-variadic template.

Comment: This code contains a *forward-declaration* of a *class template*: `template <typename Re_t> class function;` and a subsequent *partial specialization* of said class template: `template <typename Re_t, typename... Args> class function<Re_t(Args...)> { /*...*/ };` (Use these terms to find more information.)

Comment: @Joseph I know it is a variadic template but I didn't knew what the <Re_t(Args...)> does after the class name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function signature-like expressions as C++ template arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642079/function-signature-like-expressions-as-c-template-arguments)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`class function<Re_t(Args...)>` defines a partial specialization of the templated class `function<T>`. Basically this allows you to write a specialization in the form of a functor, such as:

`function<int(double,unsigned)> foo = ...`

Note that you can have a variable number of arguments due to the use of `Args...`.

Comment: Thank you :) I wasn't sure what <Re_t(Args...)> does after the class name.