# Why that partial template specialization is allowed?

Tags: c++

I've looked at a partial template specialization argument-list and stumbled upon such an example

```cpp
template <typename>
class function;
template <typename ReturnValue, typename Args,typename Args2>
class function<ReturnValue(Args,Args2)>
{
    //smth
};
```

What exactly means `ReturnValue(Args,Args2)` (couse it's not a type as I know) and by what rules can I write similar things?

Thanks

Comment: This is [function signature template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642079/function-signature-like-expressions-as-c-template-arguments). Details actually can be found in this [book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design)

Comment: `ReturnValue(Args,Args2)` *is* a type (a function returning type `ReturnValue` and taking two arguments of type `Args` and `Args2`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> couse it's not a type as I know

Actually, it is. `ReturnValue(Args,Args2)` is the type "function taking `Args` and `Arg2` and returning `ReturnValue`". Take this example:

```
void foo(int, char);
typedef void FunctionType(int, char);
```

Here, `FunctionType` is indeed the type `void(int, char)`, which is also the type of `foo`.

Comment: But why I can't modify the example above like this: ```class function<ReturnValue(Args),Args2>``` ?

Comment: @Poarthur Because `function` has *one* template parameter, while you'd be passing *two* arguments: the type `ReturnValue(Args)`, and the type `Args2`.